# <add key="SMTPServer" value="127.0.0.1" />

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to set up on web server locally for SMTP mail.

I am maintaining a web application, when i look at the deployed web config file,
I notice the following entry in the web config

I wanted to know, how can I find the settings on the web server.

Please help?

Answer (score 1):

`<add key=“SMTPServer” value=“127.0.0.1” />` doesn't mean there is a  SMTP Server in your local. This is just a key-value data that stored inside your `Web.config` file which can be called anywhere in your web application, with:

```
string example = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServer"]
//and then example = "127.0.0.1"
```

Nothing more than that, you need to search in your application, where does the app call this key `["SMTPServer"]`

Most of the time, it will be handle by `SmtpClient` class. You can find plenty of examples on Google. If it's more complicated than that, post more information.

***EDIT***

After research, found out you only can send email locally via IIS, if you have IIS 6. Else, you will need an SMTP Server locally to send email via local machine.

Comment: Value which is mentioned as 127.0.0.1 is the local server. Otherwise we mention the server name, not as 127.0.0.1 This is the first time, i see this instead of server name.

Comment: @PCDev Correct, this means that, this application is using local to send email. Please check whether does your application using SmtpClient. Because you don't need a SMTP Server to send email. Also, take note that, most of the time web.config file in development server is different with production server. Secondly, even if you deploy this application in production server, it's still correct. Like I said, meaning this application send email <b>From</b> this hosting server itself

Comment: Thanks for the reply, When we use local to send mails, what additional steps required to make it happen. For example, if i move the deploy the code to some other server, does the same settings will work with out any additional changes on the new server?

Comment: @PCDev well, port 25 need to be opened, or depend on your application setting, but by default smtp send via port 25. Sometimes it may contains credential too. You can try publish the application and test it locally first. If it was set locally, there is a high chance that machine may have installed a 3rd party email server.